# Ideas to improve language detection between Spanish and Catalan

Tags: python, language-detection

I'm working on a text mining script in python. I need to detect the language of a natural language field from the dataset.

The thing is, 98% of the rows are in Spanish and Catalan. I tried using some algorithms like the `stopwords` one or the `langdetect` library, but these languages share a lot of words so they fail a lot.

I'm looking for some ideas to improve this algorithm.

One thought is, make a dictionary with some words that are specific to Spanish and Catalan, so if one text has any of these words, it's tagged as that language.

Answer (score 2):

### Approach 1: Distinguishing characters

[Spanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Language_recognition_chart#Spanish_(Espa%C3%B1ol)) and [Catalan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Language_recognition_chart#Catalan_(Catal%C3%A0)) (note: there will be exceptions for proper names and loanwords e.g. *Barça*):

```py
esp_chars = "ñÑáÁýÝ"
cat_chars = "çÇàÀèÈòÒ·ŀĿ"
```

Example:

```py
sample_texts = ["El año que es abundante de poesía, suele serlo de hambre.",
                "Cal no abandonar mai ni la tasca ni l'esperança."]

for text in sample_texts:
    if any(char in text for char in esp_chars):
        print("Spanish: {}".format(text))
    elif any(char in text for char in cat_chars):
        print("Catalan: {}".format(text))
```

```py
>>> Spanish: El año que es abundante de poesía, suele serlo de hambre.
    Catalan: Cal no abandonar mai ni la tasca ni l'esperança.
```

If this isn't sufficient, you could expand this logic to search for language exclusive digraphs, letter combinations, or words:

|  | **Spanish only** | **Catalan only** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Words | `como` `y` `su` `con` `él` `otro` | `com` `i` `seva` `amb` `ell` `altre` |
| Initial digraphs |  | `d'` `l'` |
| Digraphs |  | `ss` `tj` `qü` `l·l` `l.l` |
| Terminal digraphs |  | `ig` |

**Catalan letter combinations that only marginally appear in Spanish**

- `tx`
- `tg`          <sup>(Es. exceptions *postgrado, postgraduado, postguerra*)</sup>
- `ny`          <sup>(Es. exceptions mostly prefixed *in-, en-, con-* + *y-*)</sup>
- `ll` (terminal) <sup>(Es. exceptions (loanwords): *detall, nomparell*)</sup>

---

### Approach 2: `googletrans` library

You could also use the [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) library to detect the language:

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

for text in sample_texts:
    lang = translator.detect(text).lang
    print(lang, ":", text)
```

```py
>>> es : El año que es abundante de poesía, suele serlo de hambre.
    ca : Cal no abandonar mai ni la tasca ni l'esperança.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DicCat = ['amb','cap','dalt','damunt','des','dintre','durant','excepte','fins','per','pro','sense','sota','llei','hi','ha','més','mes','moment','órgans', 'segóns','Article','i','per','els','amb','és','com','dels','més','seu','seva','fou','també','però','als','després','aquest','fins','any','són','hi','pel','aquesta','durant','on','part','altres','anys','ciutat','cap','des','seus','tot','estat','qual','segle','quan','ja','havia','molt','rei','nom','fer','així','li','sant','encara','pels','seves','té','partit','està','mateix','pot','nord','temps','fill','només','dues','sota','lloc','això','alguns','govern','uns','aquests','mort','nou','tots','fet','sense','frança','grup','tant','terme','fa','tenir','segons','món','regne','exèrcit','segona','abans','mentre','quals','aquestes','família','catalunya','eren','poden','diferents','nova','molts','església','major','club','estats','seua','diversos','grans','què','arribar','troba','població','poble','foren','època','haver','eleccions','diverses','tipus','riu','dia','quatre','poc','regió','exemple','batalla','altre','espanya','joan','actualment','tenen','dins','llavors','centre','algunes','important','altra','terra','antic','tenia','obres','estava','pare','qui','ara','havien','començar','història','morir','majoria','qui','ara','havien','començar','història','morir','majoria']
DicEsp = ['los','y','bajo','con', 'entre','hacia','hasta','para','por','según','segun','sin','tras','más','mas','ley','capítulo','capitulo','título','titulo','momento','y','las','por','con','su','para','lo','como','más','pero','sus','le','me','sin','este','ya','cuando','todo','esta','son','también','fue','había','muy','años','hasta','desde','está','mi','porque','qué','sólo','yo','hay','vez','puede','todos','así','nos','ni','parte','tiene','él','uno','donde','bien','tiempo','mismo','ese','ahora','otro','después','te','otros','aunque','esa','eso','hace','otra','gobierno','tan','durante','siempre','día','tanto','ella','sí','dijo','sido','según','menos','año','antes','estado','sino','caso','nada','hacer','estaba','poco','estos','presidente','mayor','ante','unos','algo','hacia','casa','ellos','ayer','hecho','mucho','mientras','además','quien','momento','millones','esto','españa','hombre','están','pues','hoy','lugar','madrid','trabajo','otras','mejor','nuevo','decir','algunos','entonces','todas','días','debe','política','cómo','casi','toda','tal','luego','pasado','medio','estas','sea','tenía','nunca','aquí','ver','veces','embargo','partido','personas','grupo','cuenta','pueden','tienen','misma','nueva','cual','fueron','mujer','frente','josé','tras','cosas','fin','ciudad','he','social','tener','será','historia','muchos','juan','tipo','cuatro','dentro','nuestro','punto','dice','ello','cualquier','noche','aún','agua','parece','haber','situación','fuera','bajo','grandes','nuestra','ejemplo','acuerdo','habían','usted','estados','hizo','nadie','países','horas','posible','tarde','ley','importante','desarrollo','proceso','realidad','sentido','lado','mí','tu','cambio','allí','mano','eran','estar','san','número','sociedad','unas','centro','padre','gente','relación','cuerpo','incluso','través','último','madre','mis','modo','problema','cinco','carlos','hombres','información','ojos','muerte','nombre','algunas','público','mujeres','siglo','todavía','meses','mañana','esos','nosotros','hora','muchas','pueblo','alguna','dar','don','da','tú','derecho','verdad','maría','unidos','podría','sería','junto','cabeza','aquel','luis','cuanto','tierra','equipo','segundo','director','dicho','cierto','casos','manos','nivel','podía','familia','largo','falta','llegar','propio','ministro','cosa','primero','seguridad','hemos','mal','trata','algún','tuvo','respecto','semana','varios','real','sé','voz','paso','señor','mil','quienes','proyecto','mercado','mayoría','luz','claro','iba','éste','pesetas','orden','español','buena','quiere','aquella','programa','palabras','internacional','esas','segunda','empresa','puesto','ahí','propia','libro','igual','político','persona','últimos','ellas','total','creo','tengo','dios','española','condiciones','méxico','fuerza','solo','único','acción','amor','policía','puerta','pesar','sabe','calle','interior','tampoco','ningún','vista','campo','buen','hubiera','saber','obras','razón','niños','presencia','tema','dinero','comisión','antonio','servicio','hijo','última','ciento','estoy','hablar','dio','minutos','producción','camino','seis','quién','fondo','dirección','papel','demás','idea','especial','diferentes','dado','base','capital','ambos','europa','libertad','relaciones','espacio','medios','ir','actual','población','empresas','estudio','salud','servicios','haya','principio','siendo','cultura','anterior','alto','media','mediante','primeros','arte','paz','sector','imagen','medida','deben','datos','consejo','personal','interés','julio','grupos','miembros','ninguna','existe','cara','edad','movimiento','visto','llegó','puntos','actividad','bueno','uso','niño','difícil','joven','futuro','aquellos','mes','pronto','soy','hacía','nuevos','nuestros','estaban','posibilidad','sigue','cerca','resultados','educación','atención','gonzález','capacidad','efecto','necesario','valor','aire','investigación','siguiente','figura','central','comunidad','necesidad','serie','organizació','nuevas','calidad']
DicEng = ['all','my','have','do','and', 'or', 'what', 'can', 'you', 'the', 'on', 'it', 'at', 'since', 'for', 'ago', 'before', 'past', 'by', 'next', 'from','with', 'wich','law','is','the','of','and','to','in','is','you','that','it','he','was','for','on','are','as','with','his','they','at','be','this','have','from','or','one','had','by','word','but','not','what','all','were','we','when','your','can','said','there','use','an','each','which','she','do','how','their','if','will','up','other','about','out','many','then','them','these','so','some','her','would','make','like','him','into','time','has','look','two','more','write','go','see','number','no','way','could','people','my','than','first','water','been','call','who','oil','its','now','find','long','down','day','did','get','come','made','may','part','may','part']


def WhichLanguage(text):
    Input = text.lower().split(" ")
    CatScore = []
    EspScore = []
    EngScore = []

    for e in Input:
        if e in DicCat:
            CatScore.append(e)
        if e in DicEsp:
            EspScore.append(e)
        if e in DicEng:
            EngScore.append(e)

    if(len(EngScore) > len(EspScore)) and (len(EngScore) > len(CatScore)):
        Language ='English'
    else:
        if(len(CatScore) > len(EspScore)):
            Language ='Catala'
        else:
            Language ='Espanyol'
    print(text)
    print("ESP= ",len(EspScore),EspScore)    
    print("Cat = ",len(CatScore), CatScore)
    print("ING= ",len(EngScore),EngScore)
    print( 'Language is =', Language)
    print("-----")
    return(Language)


print(WhichLanguage("Hola bon dia"))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.